# About shared ptr

Tags: c, garbage-collection, shared-ptr

I'm not sure whether it's strict to say, but I'd like to treat shared ptr as a garbage collection strategy.

I've two questions here:

1. When is shared ptr appropriate for garbage collection; and when other strategies such as mark-sweep?
2. Is there any lib implemented shared ptr in C?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by treating shared ptr as a garbage collection strategy? Do you mean comparing the shared pointers (termed Reference Counting in the GC world) and mark-sweep? I think boost implements shared pointers: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm.

Read more about this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417481/pointers-smart-pointers-or-shared-pointers

Comment: @smichak Yes, I'd like to see some comparisons among different garbage collection techniques for Q1.

Answer (score 3):

If you want garbage collection in C, have a look at the [Hans Boehm](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/) garbage collection library.

Shared ptr removes much of the necessity of handling object deletion, but has a number of complications: only one shared pointer can hold the pointer at a time. You might want to look also at [Boost's smart_ptr pointer handling](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm) and related classes.

But shared_ptr, and Boost, is C++. You will struggle to achieve this in C: shared_ptr relies on operator overloading to achieve its magic. Without operator overloading, you have no way of knowing if someone, somewhere, is holding a copy of your pointer. (This is a problem also in C++, but the operator overloading reduces the risk if you use shared_ptr throughout your code.)

I would definitely recommend Hans Boehm instead.

Comment: That lib is cool, I'll check it. I'd like to get some ideas before get a lib. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few good articles that talk about this:

[Garbage Collection Synopsis, and C++](http://herbsutter.com/2011/10/25/garbage-collection-synopsis-and-c/)

Previous Similar Question on StackOverflow: [Garbage collection vs. shared pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663385/garbage-collection-vs-shared-pointers)

I would also recommend you look into scoped_ptr.  Here's the differences:
[shared_ptr vs scoped_ptr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770636/shared-ptr-vs-scoped-ptr)

Comment: The OP is asking about C, not C++. I'm not sure what you posted applies to C easily.

Comment: @Aayush Some explanations in those articles are nice and useful.